# Get size of pane after resize

Tags: jquery, css, layout, jquery-layout

I am using jQuery Layout. I have a very simple layout with one vertical pane (west). Is it possible to get the size of the west pane after it has been resized.
Below is a code snippet of an example where a call to a function happens on the resize event. I would like to get the new size after the resize, is this possible?

```
var myLayout;
set_layout();
function set_layout(){
  myLayout = $("#my-div").layout({
    west:{
    size: 280,
    fxName: "slide",
    fxSpeed: 500,
    onresize_end: function(){ get_width(); }
    }
  });
}

function get_width(){
  code to get the WIDTH
}
```

Comment: did you tried  $("#my-div").width(); ?

Comment: Hi Sangita, yes I tried that. The result of that is the width of the window size and not the width of the new west pane size

Comment: ok. Did you try to add afte page load? like $(window).onload(function(){ $("#my-div").width(); });

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. I was queering the wrong DIV element.  Once I queried the width of the correct DIV I got what I want.  I needed to query a DIV element inside #my-div element.